# Project Euler #22 - why is my total off by 324536?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do problem #22 in python and my answer is off. I've gone through the list and tried certain names and they've been calculated correctly (I think).

Can anyone help??

## Problem:

> Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text
> file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it
> into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for
> each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the
> list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN,
> which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the
> list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.

What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

```
def letter_sum(word):
    total = 0
    for letter in word:
        total += ord(letter) - ord('A') + 1
    return total

def namescore(name, count):
    name_sum = letter_sum(name)
    return count * name_sum

def main():
    names = []
    f = open('p022_names.txt', 'r')
    string = f.read()
    f.close()

    total = 0
    names = sorted(string.replace('"', '').split(','))
    for i in range(len(names)):
        total += namescore(names[i], i)
    
    print total
```

Comment: Mind briefly telling us again what #22 is about without each of us having to go look it up individually?

Comment: You're multiplying by `i` when calling `namescore`, which starts from 0. I think that is the issue.

Comment: In your list of sorted names, after the split(","), "COLIN" in your list is in 939th place, not in 938th. The Euler challenge says it should be at position 938.

Comment: As an aside, you might find [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) useful for looping through lists like this: `for i, name in enumerate(names, start=1): total += namescore(name, i)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexing is off by one. `'COLIN'` is at index `937` on `0` based indexing but the assignment uses `1` based indexing. You could fix the issue by changing your code a bit:

```
total += namescore(names[i], i + 1)
```

Comment: oops. had a different mistake before where 'COLIN' was at 938 and i must've not checked after i corrected it. 

thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It's off-by-one error. In the code:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    total += namescore(names[i], i)
```

`i` starts from `0`, while the name should start counting from `1`, use `namescore(names[i], i + 1)` instead.